# Magento event "sales_order_creditmemo_save_after" taking long time to set the data

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I have created a custom module and used event `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`, here is my event code:

```
    <sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
        <observers>
            <stocksync_stockupdate>
                <class>Test_Stocksync_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>refundOrderInventory</method>
            </stocksync_stockupdate>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_creditmemo_save_after>
```

Observer code :

```
public function refundOrderInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
  $creditmemo = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo();
  foreach ($creditmemo->getAllItems() as $item) {

   Mage::helper('stocksync')->syncStock($item->getSku(),$currentstock->getQty());   
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the value through helper,everything working fine,The problem is that,when I generate the credit memo, it keeps loading, taking much time to set the data. Any best way to do the same ?

Thanks